# How to properly render collection in a partial layout from inside another partial layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, yield

I have a Cart that I want to render in 3 different ways in my app.

1. In the sidebar. Displays only item count in cart and their total price.
2. In Cart main view. Displays line items with links to products, quantity and total price for each item. Also displays buttons to increase/decrease item quantity and a button to remove item from cart.
3. In Order view, shows cart content the same way as main cart view, except links to products, buttons to change quantities and 'remove' button.

So far I render cart like this:

`carts/_cart.html.erb`

```
<%= yield %>
```

Cart sidebar layout `carts/_sidebar.html.erb`

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-header">Your Cart (<%= pluralize(@cart.total_items, "Item") %>)</li>
  <li>Total Due: <%= number_to_euro(@cart.total_price) %></li>
  <% unless @cart.line_items.empty? %>
  <li><%= link_to "View Cart & Checkout", cart_path(@cart) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Empty Cart", @cart, :method => :delete %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Which is rendered from `layouts/_sidebar.html.erb` by `<%= render :partial => 'carts/cart', :layout => 'carts/sidebar' %>`

Cart main layout `carts/_main.html.erb`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <%= render @line_items %>
  <tr id="total_line">
    <td colspan="3">Total:</td>
    <td><%= number_to_euro(@cart.total_price) %></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Which is rendered from `carts/show.html.erb`

```
<h1><%= pluralize(@cart.total_items, "Item") %> in Your Cart</h1>
<%= render :partial => 'cart/cart', :layout => 'carts/main' %>
<%= link_to "Empty Cart", @cart, :method => :delete %>
<%= link_to "Checkout", new_order_path %>
```

And there is also `carts/_order.html.erb` which is currently rendered from `orders/new.html.erb` the same way as in cart main view.

What I want to do is to create 2 different layouts to render line items from `carts/show.html.erb` and `orders/new.html.erb`. And to do so, I have `<%= yield %>` in `line_items/_line_item.html.erb`

Line items layout for cart main layout `line_items/_main.html.erb`

```
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to "#{line_item.product.brand.name} #{line_item.product.title}", product_path(line_item.product) %></td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to "-", decrement_line_item_path(line_item), :method => :post %>
    <%= line_item.quantity %>
    <%= link_to "+", increment_line_item_path(line_item), :method => :post %>
  </td>
  <td><%= number_to_euro(line_item.product.price) %></td>
  <td><%= number_to_euro(line_item.total_price) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Remove"), line_item, :method => :delete %></td>
</tr>
```

And similar line items layout for new order view `line_items/_order.html.erb`

```
<tr>
  <td><%= "#{line_item.product.brand.name} #{line_item.product.title}" %></td>
  <td><%= line_item.quantity %></td>
  <td><%= number_to_euro(line_item.product.price) %></td>
  <td><%= number_to_euro(line_item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
```

This is where the problem starts. I don't understand how to render collection. I tried rendering line items from `carts/_main.html.erb` like this

```
<%= render :partial => 'line_items/line_item', :layout => 'line_items/main', :collection => @line_items %>
```

And from `carts/_order.html.erb` like this

```
<%= render :partial => 'line_items/line_item', :layout => 'line_items/order', :collection => @line_items %>
```

But I get LocalJumpError in Carts#show

```
Showing app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb where line #1 raised:

no block given (yield)
```

Any other :collection name simply renders nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I understand what I've done wrong. First of all, the error message `no block given (yield)` means there is nothing to yield. And second, there is no need to use :layout when rendering partials in this case.

To render a cart from `layouts/_sidebar.html.erb` simply call `<%= render :partial => 'carts/sidebar' %>`.

There is one thing I didn't know about. When rendering partial with collection, the second part of :partial name becomes local variable name inside that collection.

This is the partial for main cart view (`carts/_cart.html.erb`):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Product</th>
    <td>Price</th>
    <td>Quantity</th>
    <td>Subtotal</th>
    <td></th>
  </tr>
  <%= render :partial => 'line_items/cart_item', :collection => @line_items %>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Total:</td>
    <td><%= number_to_euro(@cart.total_price) %></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Which can be rendered by `<%= render @cart %>`. Notice the `/cart_item` part in `:partial` name. That's how we refer to collection items in `line_items/_cart_item.html.erb`:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to "#{cart_item.product.brand.name} #{cart_item.product.title}", product_path(cart_item.product) %></td>
  <td><%= number_to_euro(cart_item.product.price) %></td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to "-"), decrement_line_item_path(cart_item), :method => :post %>
    <%= cart_item.quantity %>
    <%= link_to "+"), increment_line_item_path(cart_item), :method => :post %>
  </td>
  <td><%= number_to_euro(cart_item.total_price) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Remove"), cart_item, :method => :delete %></td>
</tr>
```

And the same way with cart shown in Orders controller. `carts/_order.html.erb`:

```
...
<%= render :partial => 'line_items/order_item', :collection => @line_items %>
...
```

`line_items/_order_item.html.erb`:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= "#{order_item.product.brand.name} #{order_item.product.title}"%></td>
  <td><%= number_to_euro(order_item.product.price) %></td>
  <td>&times; <%= order_item.quantity %></td>
  <td><%= number_to_euro(order_item.total_price) %></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Hope it all makes sense.